# What is the best way to persist an object graph using LinqToSql?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have an Entity with a lot of associated entities which I'm trying to persist using `LinqToSql`, comming from the `NHibernate` world i used to create that Entity like this

```
// UI layer
var entity1 = new Entity1();

entity1.Entity2 = new Entity2 { Id =  long.Parse(dropdown.SelectedValue) };
entity1.Entity3 = new Entity3 { Id =  long.Parse(dropdown2.SelectedValue) };
...
entity1.List = GetEntities();
...

//DAO layer
public void Insert(Entity1 entity)
{
   dataContext.Entity1.InsertOnSubmit(entity);                                  
   dataContext.SubmitChanges();                                            
}
```

when i call the `dbContext.SubmitChanges()` method in the `DAO` layer
`LinqToSql` try to persist also the associated classes, which it has not to do, i know that to solve this problem i have to attach those entities to the current `dataContext`.

so my question is how do you handle situation like this and what is the best way to persist an object graph using `LinqToSql` 
:

- Instansiate the associated classes like the above example and then attach theme to the `datacontext`
- or load theme directly from the database ?

thanks for help.

Comment: Coming from the NHibernate world and dealing with entities, you'd rather should user (if possible) Entity Framework instead of going through Linq2Sql. Just a thought, not an answer to your question ;)

Comment: @darkey LinqToSql is quite sufficient, at least for now.